How to use `git diff-index --check` in `.git/hooks/pre-commit` without "new blank line at EOF." when you end files with '\n'?
git ships with .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample.
Used:
cp .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample .git/hooks/pre-commit 
sed -i'' 's/diff-index --check/\0 --ignore-blank-lines/g' ".git/hooks/pre-commit"
echo '#/bin/sh
' > w
git add w
git commit

, got:
$ cp .git/hooks/pre-commit.sample .git/hooks/pre-commit 
$ sed -i'' 's/diff-index --check/\0 --ignore-blank-lines/g' ".git/hooks/pre-commit"
$ echo '#/bin/sh
' > w
$ git add w
$ git commit
w:2: new blank line at EOF.

. It is recommended practice to end files with '\n'; how to allow this?
https://www.google.com/search?q=%22--ignore-blank-lines%22%20but%20%22new%20blank%20line%20at%20EOF.%22 has no results; is this just a problem with Termux's version of git? Do not have other systems to test this now.

How to allow what? What does the /n argument do? Perhaps take some time to understand what that argument does and why it is recommended practice to end files with it.

I wonder if op essentially means a new line?
